# MIPS Why I can't print the selected array position?

Tags: arrays, string, printing, mips

Whit this code the simulator says: memory addres out of bound" and print(null)
t0 is the index, initially set to 0, it's portion of a cicle.

```
        la $t1, nome #array address
        mul $t2, $t0, 4 # t2=index*4
        add $t3, $t2, $t1 

        lw $a0, nome($t2)
        li $v0, 4
        syscall
```

That's the write:

```
        la $t1, nome 
        mul $t2, $s2, 4 #s2 index

        la $v0, 4 
        la $a0, nomedom #input string
        syscall 
        li $v0, 8 
        syscall
        sw $v0, nome($t2)
```

Here the proto of the program, i just leaved one array for reducing lenght
Now, if you run this code you can run just creation and list, but if you run list after create a profile, function list will not listing nothing, but i guess I read the same memory location.. after that, if you run another time creation it will print on screen the precedent data!! And i don't understeand why! I don't print anything more than the question for the input

```
.data #variabili


nome: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
cognome: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
interessi: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
userid: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
email: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
password: .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
pp: .byte 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
cont: .word 0 #METTERE STO CONTATORE COME RIFERIMENTO INDIRIZZO NEGLI INDICI DEGLI ARRAY


selezione: .byte 0

#menu
menu: .asciiz "\n\n\n\n\n\n1)Creation profile\n2)Modificare il proprio  profilo\n3)Cancellare \n4)LIST\n5)Cercare un profilo pubblico per nome e cognome\n0)USCITA\n\n\nSelezione: "
nomedom: .asciiz "Inserire nome: "
cognomedom: .asciiz "Inserire cognome: "
useriddom: .asciiz "Inserire UserID: "
interessidom: .asciiz "Inserire interessi: "
emaildom: .asciiz "Inserire E-mail valida: "
passdom: .asciiz "Inserire password: "
ppdom: .asciiz "Profilo pubblico(0) o privato(1): "
menurid: .asciiz "\n\n\nModifica Profilo(1)\nMenu principale(0)  :"
uscita: .asciiz "SEI USCITO"
intro: .asciiz "             --------"
troppitx: .asciiz "\n\nIL NUMERO MASSIMO DI PROFILI È 10"
.text


main:
li $s2, 0
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, intro 
syscall

menupri: 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------<<<<<<<MENU
    li $v0, 4 # 4 è il codice di print_string
la $a0, menu # domanda all'utente
syscall
li $v0, 5 #leggo intero
syscall
move $t6,$v0 #memorizzo l'intero in t6

li $t1, 1
li $t2, 2
li $t3, 3
li $t4, 4
li $t5, 5
li $t0, 0
beq $t1, $t6, FUNZIONE_CREATION 
beq $t2, $t6, FUNZIONE_MODIFICA
beq $t3, $t6, FUNZIONE_CANCELLAZIONE
beq $t4, $t6, FUNZIONE_LIST
beq $t5, $t6, FUNZIONE_RICERCA
beq $t0, $t6, USCITA



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------<<<<FUNCTION


.ent FUNZIONE_CREATION
FUNZIONE_CREATION:






bgeu $s2, 10, TROPPI #s2 indice e contatore




li $t1, 0
li $t2, 0
li $t3, 0
        la $t1, nome #indirizzo dell'array
        mul $t2, $s2, 4 #di quanto devo spostarmi t2=indice*4
        add $t3, $t2, $t1 #indirizzo array di indice s2 è in t3  



la $v0, 4 #nomedom
la $a0, nomedom
syscall #scrivo richiesta
li $v0, 8 # lettura
syscall
sw $v0, nome($t2)


add $s7, $s7, 1

li $v0, 4 # 4 è il codice di print_string
la $a0, menurid # domanda all'utente
syscall
li $v0, 5 #leggo intero
syscall
move $t2,$v0 #memorizzo l'intero in t2
li $t1, 1
li $t0, 0
beq $t1, $t2, FUNZIONE_MODIFICA #VA PASSATO L'INDICE COME ARGOMENTO
beq $t0, $t2, esci
esci:
#niente

.end FUNZIONE_CREATION
j menupri  #torna al menu principale


.ent FUNZIONE_LIST
FUNZIONE_LIST:

#VISUALIZZA I PROFILI PUBBLICI, se pp= pubblico di un indice scrive
li $t0, 0#indice e contatore
li $t7, 0
li $t1, 0
li $t2, 0
li $t3, 0
li $t5, 0
loop:
bgt $t0, 9, esci1


        la $t1, nome #indirizzo dell'array
        mul $t2, $t0, 4 #di quanto devo spostarmi t2=indice*4
        add $t3, $t2, $t1 #indirizzo array di indice t0 è in t3  


#lw $t7, pp
beq $t7, $zero, scrittura #t7 è pp
scrittura:

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, nome($t2)

        syscall


addi $t0, $t0,1 #condizione e campi del ciclo #prima era sotto bgt
j loop
esci1:
#niente

.end FUNZIONE_LIST
j menupri  #torna al menu principale

.ent FUNZIONE_RICERCA
FUNZIONE_RICERCA:
.end FUNZIONE_RICERCA
j menupri  #torna al menu principale

.ent FUNZIONE_MODIFICA
FUNZIONE_MODIFICA:



.end FUNZIONE_MODIFICA
j menupri  #torna al menu principale

.ent FUNZIONE_CANCELLAZIONE
FUNZIONE_CANCELLAZIONE:
.end FUNZIONE_CANCELLAZIONE
j menupri  #torna al menu principale


.ent USCITAMEN
USCITAMEN:
j menupri
.end USCITAMEN


.ent TROPPI
TROPPI:
li $v0, 4 
la $a0, troppitx
syscall
    j menupri
.end USCITAMEN



#fine
USCITA: 
li $v0, 4 # uscita
la $a0, uscita
syscall
li $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: You should post the _complete_ minimal source code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I put the minimal source code, do you understand like this? I modified to english most important comment or name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want `nome` to be an array of integers. In that case, you should be having `$v0 = 1` instead of `$v0 = 4`. `4` in `$v0` prints a string. Since `nome` has `0` at each location, the value of `4` in `$v0` prints `0` as an ASCII. And `0` is the ASCII value of `NULL`. This explains your undesired output.

If you want to print `0` as an integer, you need `$v0=1`.

Change this:

```
lw $a0, nome($t2)
li $v0, 4
syscall
```

to this:

```
lw $a0, 0($t3)    # Since you have $t3 = $t2 + $t1
li $v0, 1         # It is same as Address of nome[0] + index*4
syscall           # which is same as Address of nome[i]; i being $t2
```

Comment: No, nome is an array of string, I can see ten 0 printed now, but i put a string in the first 4byte of the nome array whit the function CREATION(I have to create a profile like facebook).

Comment: From your .data section, it looks like `nome` is an array of 10 words, all set to 0x0000 0000. How are you planning to deal with the string?

Comment: I supposed that in this way I initialized an array of 10 element of 4 byte for each, maybe my problem is in the array declaration?

Comment: You are right. You declared an array of 10 elements of 4 byte each with each byte to be 0000 0000 initially. This can be used as an array of 10 elements where each element can have 4 characters, not an entire string. Because in MIPS, the size of each element of the array has to be same (which is 4 bytes here). But strings have unfixed length, so you can not create an array of string like this. I can probably help you if you explain me your aim.

Comment: I will really appreciate you help, my problem is basically create an array of strings and then modify and print this strings, they will be generated by user input.. I can't find any problem like this anywhere! For testing i'm putting in input just "aa" but it don't work

Comment: So, how to declare an array of strings? I suppose that I load and store it in the right way, or not?

Comment: The way I used to implement an array of string was to keep an array of addresses, since each address is 4 bytes. So fixed size. And at each address, I would store one string.

Comment: I was trying this method right now, but i don't know the procedure, can you make me an exaple?

Comment: It's : array: .word add1, add2.... ? How can I access to an index during a loop? I have to load the address of the array, then load the address of the index position, but then? How i can use the word like an address?

Comment: I solved my problem with the addres, thank you! Now it print the string!!

Comment: I could have tried to help more from the beginning, but I did not understand the question correctly at first. Good you figured it out.